# How to setState on Object item within array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I want to update state of key heart in the array's objects when the heart icon pressed it changes to red so for this I'm using react native icons and i'm using heart and hearto to switch when click on it

**here is the code:**

```
state = {      
          localAdversiment: [
            {
              title: "Ecloninear 871",
              image: require("../../assets/images/truck_image.png"),
              year: "2015",
              type: "Truck",
              status: "new",
              price: "$ 2000",
              heart: "hearto"
            }
```

**Here it function which is called when heart icon pressed**

```
 handleFavourite = index => {
    const { heart } = this.state.localAdversiment[index];
    this.setState(
      {
        heart: "heart"
      }
    );
  };
```

**here is the heart icon code**

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.handleFavourite(index)}>
                <Icon
                  name={item.heart}
                  type={"AntDesign"}
                  style={{ fontSize: 18 }}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
```

kindly help me how to update heart as heart instead of hearto when clicked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it easily by following approach

```
state = {      
          localAdversiment: [
            {
              id: 0,
              title: "Ecloninear 871",
              image: require("../../assets/images/truck_image.png"),
              year: "2015",
              type: "Truck",
              status: "new",
              price: "$ 2000",
              heart: "hearto",
              selected: false
            }
}
```

now in onPress do this

```
handleFavourite = (item) => {
   const { id } = item;
   this.setState({
       localAdvertisement: this.state.localAdvertisement.map((item) => {
         if(item.id === id){
           return {
              ...item,
              selected: !item.selected  
           }
         }

         return item

    })
  })
};
```

Now render like this

```
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.handleFavourite(item)}>
                <Icon
                  name={item.selected ? "heart" : 'hearto'}
                  type={"AntDesign"}
                  style={{ fontSize: 18 }}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

Edit this function as follows:

```
handleFavourite = index => {
    let updatedlocalAdversimentStates = this.state.localAdversiment;
    updatedlocalAdversimentStates[index].heart = "heart";
    this.setState(
      {
        localAdversiment: updatedlocalAdversimentStates
      }
    );
  };
```

Comment: Thanks, dear for your reply.it works partially when I click it again it  should revert back, but it not with this way

Comment: Use a bool value instead of string for heart and toggle every time it clicked. or use if else condition based on the this.state.localAdversiment[index].heart.